# CUDA error out of memory in cuCtxSynchronize()

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

I need your help about an error, this is the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Comment: That most likely means your scene is either too large too complex to fit in the memory of your graphics card. Simplify your scene, reduce texture size or quality, or use CPU rendering instead.

Comment: I was reduced tiles size and turn off my screen for the rendering time and now it is done:)